# SwiftUI: Filter Core Data fetch by relationship (NSPredicate)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@FetchRequest(
    entity: ListStruct.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ListStruct.name, ascending: true)],
    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "parentfolder == %@", parentFolder),
    animation: .default)
private var lists: FetchedResults<ListStruct>

var parentFolder: FolderStruct
```

There are two entities: FolderStruct and ListStruct. I made a tree structure with two entities. The view that I am using this code receives "var parentFolder: FolderStruct" as a parameter.

The relationship between FolderStruct and ListStruct is to-many, which means a folderStruct can hold many ListStructs. FolderStruct has a relationship named "childlists" which is to-many, and ListStruct has a relationship named "parentfolder" which is to-one.

When fetching ListStructs, I want to filter ListStructs whose parentfolder relationship is the parameter parentFolder. However, the code above makes an error that says "Cannot use instance member 'parentFolder' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available". How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The new `FetchRequest` is unnecessary `parentFolder.childlists` already has the items `Array(parentFolder.childlists.allObjects)` will give you an array

Comment: @loremipsum Sorry but I cannot understand your explanation completely. Do you mean I don't need to use FetchRequest and filter from Array(parentFolder.childlists.allObjects)? If so, how can I use filter in an array?

Comment: What filter do you mean, with the suggestion from @loremipsum you already have an array of all children for the given parent?

Comment: Where ever you want to use `lists` just type `Array(parentFolder.childlists.allObjects)`

Comment: I solved it. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supply the param you want to use in the fetch to the `View`'s `init` as follows:

```
private var fetchRequest : FetchRequest<Item>
private var items: FetchedResults<Item> {
    fetchRequest.wrappedValue
}

init(folder: Folder) {
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.name, ascending: true)],
    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "folder == %@", folder),
    animation: .default)
}
```

Just so you know, due to a [bug in FetchRequest](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5516608613122048), the body func will be called every time this View is init even if nothing has changed, so you may wish to wrap it in another `View` that takes the `folder` as a let for a layer of protection.

Another bug is if you "dynamically change the predicate or sort descriptors" like the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchrequest) states, then when the View containing the `@FetchRequest` is re-init, those changes are lost.