# How to filter with NSPredicate by an attribute of an Element I pass from the parent view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

Please help me with the following question - how do I filter a fetchRequest by an attribute of an Element **I pass from the parent view**?

```
import SwiftUI

struct aListDetailView: View {

@State var aParameter: String

@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "elementIdentificationAttribute == %@", aParameter)) var contracts: FetchedResults<Contract>


var body: some View {
  List {...}

...}
```

I get "Cannot use instance member 'aContract' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available".

I understand why, but how do I bypass this?

My example is a simplified version.

In truth, my query is this: I have a list of Contract elements, and each contract has a list of invoices issued in regards to that specific contract. Each contract **has a unique serial code** I give it, as an attribute.

My @FetchRequest for a list of all Contract elements **is in Content View**. I loop through them to create a list. Each row of the list is a NavigationLink to a new view, and I pass the specific contract element to the new view.

In the new view, I need to fetch a list of all the invoices specific to that contract.

However, when I add a new invoice to create a new row in the invoice sub-view list, core data does not show the new row, for a new invoice. The new row appears only when I return to the Content View and back to the invoice view, because my @FetchRequest for Contracts is in Content View.

I thought I could bypass this issue through a @FetchRequest for a list of contracts that have an attribute of my choosing (say, an attribute contractSerialNumber) equal to the attribute instance of the contract I pass to this view.

Something like:

```
@FetchRequest that filters all contracts in storage by the specific, unique attribute of my choosing of the contract I passed from the Parent View. Places them in a list.

ForEach contract that has that particular attribute (which will be a list of one contract) {
 ForEach contract.invoiceArray { invoice in
   Text(contract.invoice.invoiceIdentificationAttribute
    } }
```

Thank you!

Comment: If Contract has a relationship to Invoice then you don’t need a fetch request for Invoice but you can directly access them via that relationship

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Indeed, I proceed as such. My issue is that on the Invoice List view (so the child view), whenever I add a new instance of Invoice to the list, the list does not reload automatically. I need to return to the parent view and access the sub-view again to get the list to reload.

Comment: @ChrisR Thank you, I follow the website. In that lesson, however, Paul Hudson has a hardcoded default string. He filters either by a default String or switches the filter to another String. In my situation, I have a  State var as my filter, with no default value, as it takes on the value of an entity from the previous view. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson s approach is right –  how did you pass the contract into the subview? In the subview it should be declared as `@ObservedObject var contract: Contract` then the invoice relationships should also update. Try it, if not I can post an example code.

Comment: @ChrisR Yes, that was the issue :D Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: Filter Core Data fetch by relationship (NSPredicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71624237/swiftui-filter-core-data-fetch-by-relationship-nspredicate)